# OAuthTokenCredential throws Certificate Exception

Tags: grails, paypal, oauth-2.0

I implemented PayPal on Grails but I am not able to create OAuthToken. When I try to create token Security Exception is thrown.

My code to generate token is

```
String accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(configVal.clientId, configVal.clientSecret, sdkConfig).getAccessToken();
```

and Exception is

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available

 Caused by CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available

executeWithStream    in com.paypal.base.HttpConnection
 generateAccessToken  in com.paypal.base.rest.OAuthTokenCredential
```

Comment: Do you have the ssl certificate configured to your site / application (https)?

Comment: SSL certificate is not configured. Its bypassed.